# A Bug in Form display code

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<?php
$email=$_POST['email'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];

$to = "my@address.com";
$subject = "Comments";
$message = 
"
 Name:-             " . $name .     "\r\n   
 Email:-            " . $email .    "\r\n 
 Comments:-     " . $comments .                  

$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";

if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  print "<script>document.location.href='http://thesite.org/docs/tkx.html';</script>";

}
else
{
  echo "Error! Please try again.";
}

?>
```

But for reasons I cannot detect, when the data is delivered to my email it included the 'email address' data AGAIN at the end of the 'comments' data

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.
OzWaz

Comment: Your `$message` declaration should end with `;`, not `.`, which concats your `$headers` variable at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Remove last dot from here

```
 Comments:-     " . $comments .
```

So it should be

```
 Comments:-     " . $comments;
```

Right now you are connecting another line to $message ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = 
"
 Name:-             " . $name .     "\r\n   
 Email:-            " . $email .    "\r\n 
 Comments:-     " . $comments .
```

Just remove dot(.) from end of line so it not concatenate with below header line.
It should be

```
$message = 
"
 Name:-             " . $name .     "\r\n   
 Email:-            " . $email .    "\r\n 
 Comments:-     " . $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 
"
Name:-             " . $name .     "\r\n   
Email:-            " . $email .    "\r\n 
Comments:-     " . $comments;                  

$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";
```

You were contacenating another line `$headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";` to the `$message` string